# AWK /Unix command: How to delete rows when multiple column having zero values

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file with 50,000 row and 200 column, most of values in row/column are zero, so I want to delete all rows , when there are more than 100 column having zero values.

Please suggest me any AWK/ unix command.

Thanks

Comment: Read [ask] then [edit] your question to contain a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: Do you need to distinguish between 'empty' fields and fields with an explicit 0 value?  You should provide the MCVE that was asked for, but you'd scale it down so you had perhaps 10-20 columns and 5-10 rows of data, and needed to reject rows with more than 5 zeros, for example.  By all means indicate the size of the full-scale problem; that's helpful.  But your MCVE should be much smaller.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an `awk` script that will count the number of zero-valued fields in each record (row) of input, and only output the record if this count does not reach above 100.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
    zcount = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        if ($i == 0)
            ++zcount;
        if (zcount > 100)
            next;
    }

    print;
}
```

To run it, first make it executable:

```
$ chmod script.awk
```

Then, assuming your data is in the file `data.in`:

```
$ ./script.awk data.in
```

Alternatively, without making it executable:

```
$ awk -f script.awk data.in
```

The following variation of the script allows you to specify the maximum number of zeroes that you want to allow:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { if (zmax == 0) zmax = 100 }

{
    zcount = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        if ($i == 0)
            ++zcount;
        if (zcount >= zmax)
            next;
    }

    print;
}
```

You run this with

```
$ ./script.awk -v zmax=90 data.in
```

The second script will default to 100 if you leave `-v zmax=N` out.

Comment: Others have produced snappy one-liners. I, however, would like to think of my solution as "robust".   :-)

Answer (score 1):

This MIGHT be what you need:

```
awk 'gsub(/(^|[[:space:]])0([[:space:]]|$)/,"&")<100' file
```

but without seeing some sample input/output we're guessing.

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=" +0 +"} NF<100' file
```

Comment: will miss the first field though.

Comment: There might be an off-by-one error there. Tested it with 2 rather than 100 and it filters out "0 0 1".

Comment: That is due to not checking first field.